# I/flutter (32524): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have this error ("type 'String' is not a sub type of type 'int' of 'index'")

but i don't know where the problem is or which line, the compiler don't tell me which line the error is,

here is the code:

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>(
          create: (_) =>
              Auth(), //lezem nekten l auth abel l prodect li2an l prodect ya3tamed 3le
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          // 2 provider product ya3tamed 3ala auth
          update: (ctx, value, previousProduct) => Products(value.token,
              previousProduct==null? []: previousProduct.productsList),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Auth>(
      builder: (ctx, value, _) => MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.orange,
            canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 238, 219, 1)),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: value.isAuth? MyHomePage(): AuthScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchData()
        .then((_) => _isLoading = false)
        .catchError((onError) => print(onError));

    super.initState();
  }

  Widget detailCard(id, tile, desc, price, imageUrl) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (innerContext) => FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(id);
          Navigator.push(
            innerContext,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ProductDetails(id)),
          ).then(
              (id) => Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).delete(id));
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Card(
              elevation: 10,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(115, 138, 119, 1),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                      width: 130,
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: id,
                        child: Image.network(imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                          tile,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Divider(color: Colors.white),
                        Container(
                          width: 200,
                          child: Text(
                            desc,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                            softWrap: true,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                            maxLines: 3,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Divider(color: Colors.white),
                        Text(
                          "\$$price",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 13),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(flex: 1, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Product> prodList =
        Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: true).productsList;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My Products')),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : (prodList.isEmpty
              ? Center(
                  child: Text('No Products Added.',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)))
              : RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: () async =>
                      await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
                          .fetchData(),
                  child: ListView(
                    children: prodList
                        .map(
                          (item) => detailCard(item.id, item.title,
                              item.description, item.price, item.imageUrl),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                )),
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        width: 180,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          label: Text("Add Product",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19)),
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddProduct())),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

product.dart

```
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.imageUrl,
  });
}

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> productsList = [];

  final String authToken;

  Products(this.authToken, this.productsList);

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final url = "https://flutter-app-568d3.firebaseio.com/product.json?auth=$authToken";
    try {
      final http.Response res = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(res.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        final prodIndex =
            productsList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == prodId);
        if (prodIndex >= 0) {
          productsList[prodIndex] = Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData['title'],
            description: prodData['description'],
            price: prodData['price'],
            imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
          );
        } else {
          productsList.add(Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData['title'],
            description: prodData['description'],
            price: prodData['price'],
            imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
          ));
        }
      });

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateData(String id) async {
    final url = "https://flutter-app-568d3.firebaseio.com/product/$id.json?auth=$authToken";

    final prodIndex = productsList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      await http.patch(url,
          body: json.encode({
            "title": "new title 4",
            "description": "new description 2",
            "price": 199.8,
            "imageUrl":
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297__340.jpg",
          }));

      productsList[prodIndex] = Product(
        id: id,
        title: "new title 4",
        description: "new description 2",
        price: 199.8,
        imageUrl:
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297__340.jpg",
      );

      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print("...");
    }
  }

  Future<void> add(
      {String id,
      String title,
      String description,
      double price,
      String imageUrl}) async {
    final url = "https://flutter-app-568d3.firebaseio.com/product.json?auth=$authToken";
    try {
      http.Response res = await http.post(url,
          body: json.encode({
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "price": price,
            "imageUrl": imageUrl,
          }));
      print(json.decode(res.body));

      productsList.add(Product(
        id: json.decode(res.body)['name'],
        title: title,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
      ));
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> delete(String id) async {
    final url = "https://flutter-app-568d3.firebaseio.com/product/$id.json?auth=$authToken";

    final prodIndex = productsList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    var prodItem = productsList[prodIndex];
    productsList.removeAt(prodIndex);
    notifyListeners();

    var res = await http.delete(url);
    if (res.statusCode >= 400) {
      productsList.insert(prodIndex, prodItem);
      notifyListeners();
      print("Could not deleted item");
    } else {
      prodItem = null;
      print("Item deleted");
    }
  }
}
```

auth.dart

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _expireDate;
  String _userId;

  bool get isAuth{
    return token != null;

  }
  String get token{
    if(_expireDate != null && _expireDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) && _token != null){
      return _token;
    }return null;
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url =
        "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=AIzaSyAN1Z9ibJ9-HqBen65x5ALKiqsRTzFfhh8";

    try {
      final res = await http.post(url,
          body: json.encode({
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          }));
      print(json.decode(res.body));// byetba3 lma3lomat l rej3a ya3ni resalet l error
      final resData = json.decode(res.body);
      // to print the error
      if(resData['error'] != null){
        throw "${resData['error']['message']}";
      }
      _token = resData['idToken'];
      _userId = resData['localId'];
      _expireDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(resData['expiresIn'])));
      notifyListeners();

    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signUp(String email, String password) async {
   return _authenticate(email, password, "signUp");
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, "signInWithPassword");
  }
}
```

auth_screen.dart

```
enum AuthMode { SignUp, Login }

class AuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(215, 117, 255, 1).withOpacity(0.5),
                  Color.fromRGBO(255, 188, 117, 1).withOpacity(0.9),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0, 1],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: deviceSize.height,
              width: deviceSize.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 94.0),
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180)
                        ..translate(-10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'MyShop',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 40,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: deviceSize.width > 600 ? 2 : 1,
                    child: AuthCard(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthCard({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthCardState createState() => _AuthCardState();
}

class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  var _isLoading = false;
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("An Error Occurred"),
              content: Text(message),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text("OK")),
              ],
            ));
  }

  Future<void> _submit() async{
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
        // Log user in
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
            .login(
              _authData['email'],
              _authData['password'],
            );
      } else {
        // Sign user up
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
            .signUp(
              _authData['email'],
              _authData['password'],
            );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = "Authentication failed";
      if(error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')){
        errorMessage = 'This email address is already taken';
      }else if(error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')){
        errorMessage = 'This is not a valid email address';
      }else if(error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')){
        errorMessage = 'This password is too weak';
      } else if(error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')){
        errorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email';
      } else if(error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')){
        errorMessage = 'Invalid password';
      }
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _switchAuthMode() {
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.SignUp;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
      child: Container(
        height: _authMode == AuthMode.SignUp ? 320 : 260,
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(minHeight: _authMode == AuthMode.SignUp ? 320 : 260),
        width: deviceSize.width * 0.75,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Invalid email!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['email'] = value;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                      return 'Password is too short!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['password'] = value;
                  },
                ),
                if (_authMode == AuthMode.SignUp)
                  TextFormField(
                    enabled: _authMode == AuthMode.SignUp,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: _authMode == AuthMode.SignUp
                        ? (value) {
                            if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                              return 'Passwords do not match!';
                            }
                            return null;
                          }
                        : null,
                  ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                if (_isLoading)
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                else
                  RaisedButton(
                    child:
                        Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'),
                    onPressed: _submit,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.color,
                  ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                      '${_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGN UP' : 'LOGIN'} INSTEAD'),
                  onPressed: _switchAuthMode,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4),
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Compiler

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G610F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Waiting for SM G610F to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60889/J5CQX-fKfbs=/ws
Syncing files to device SM G610F...
I/zygote  (32524): Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
I/zygote  (32524): After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
I/zygote  (32524): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/libGLESv2(32524): STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.example.animation
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/InputMethodManager(32524): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 32524 view : com.example.animation
V/InputMethodManager(32524): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@9dca947 nm : com.example.animation ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@271e574
D/InputMethodManager(32524): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(32524): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(32524): Input channel constructed: fd=100
D/InputTransport(32524): Input channel destroyed: fd=91
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 873) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 873) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 3430410240} changed=false
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/zygote  (32524): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=61KB
I/zygote  (32524): After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=61KB
I/zygote  (32524): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 1
V/InputMethodManager(32524): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@fb092e3 nm : com.example.animation ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@981e4e0
D/InputMethodManager(32524): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(32524): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(32524): Input channel constructed: fd=94
D/InputTransport(32524): Input channel destroyed: fd=100
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32524): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/InputMethodManager(32524): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 32524 view : com.example.animation
V/InputMethodManager(32524): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@391b65e nm : com.example.animation ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@54f7a3f
D/InputMethodManager(32524): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(32524): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(32524): Input channel constructed: fd=97
D/InputTransport(32524): Input channel destroyed: fd=94
D/InputMethodManager(32524): HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 32524
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 3430410240} changed=false
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (32524): {kind: identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse, localId: urJPn2l2EBeHNGJ7MmcMMkCIJtf1, email: ali@gmail.com, displayName: , idToken: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImM0ZWFhZjkxM2VlNWY0MDY0YmE2NjUzN2M0Njk3YzY5OGE3NGYwODIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmx1dHRlci1hcHAtYjM0ZTAiLCJhdWQiOiJmbHV0dGVyLWFwcC1iMzRlMCIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTYxNDg4MzQwMywidXNlcl9pZCI6InVySlBuMmwyRUJlSE5HSjdNbWNNTWtDSUp0ZjEiLCJzdWIiOiJ1ckpQbjJsMkVCZUhOR0o3TW1jTU1rQ0lKdGYxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE0ODgzNDAzLCJleHAiOjE2MTQ4ODcwMDMsImVtYWlsIjoiYWxpQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJhbGlAZ21haWwuY29tIl19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoicGFzc3dvcmQifX0.XfeiI4-UqDcaugW1mQxaoQbrk-h_NclPANgKKt0w36H6Jj32mGdUV-pZ_WdXdfMRxnF9lJEt9nfe0FgQSVKyYk8oLxkEaqlNJME1BnF5wUvHEJsqpHsG89mFz77cYWw-jYcjvquvPlJYSiwIc-snEyinRPx5DZwpbIkWtGe-oqWzJyE23C5inh0yu0O52tLrEDtBHy5m9qBvCK-3HLHKJ1Phrz0Q06qdH8cxw_3-AdRPqZQ8w8F4FhVOyrB04NEqWIBs-uvjAkbjo6y3LlM5PqLebrhDSdKlUlbVYOVPotMp0UMkcDRqkuZDlFZoMRoU
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 3430410240} changed=false
I/flutter (32524): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/ViewRootImpl@886418b[MainActivity](32524): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
```

I need a help please:
what i need to know is where is the error and how to solve it.
thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not quite certain, but are you sure that when you get your data in this line:
http.Response res = await http.get(url);
that prodId and price are both Strings and not of type int?

Comment: actually no,  I'am not getting any data from the database Only the progress indicator  rotate

Comment: Just as what Kim pointed out, you are either define a String variable and try to assign an int to it or you are using a String variable where you should use an int

Comment: thank you Kim and Mohammed I'm trying to find out where the problem is but didn't successes yet. I didn't find which variable should be the integer